# Are there any api call exists to validate the access token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Retrieved  access token from Cognito using client credentials grant.  Once I receive the access token from client is there any api call  exists in cognito to validate the access token ?   Want to do any sample api call using access token and check whether receiving a successful response from cognito like getting the list of users from cognito?

Answer (score 0):

See below some useful links.

1 - AWS Cognito uses Oauth2.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/

2 - TOKEN Endpoint
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

3 - pmill/aws-cognito
https://github.com/pmill/aws-cognito

4 - PHP Code:

/**
 * Get Token
 *
*/
public function getToken( $code )
{

```
$data = array(
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
  'client_id' => $this->appClientId,
  'code' => $code,
  'redirect_uri' => $this->callbackUrl,
);

$fields_string = http_build_query( $data );

$authorization = $this->appClientId.':'.$this->appClientSecret;

$headers = array(
 "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($authorization),
 "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->Token );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);

if ($err) {
  //echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  return false;
}

curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($result);

return $result;
```

}

Regards.
Eduardo Estevez.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Know how to retrieve access token.  I want to validate whether access token is a valid one by doing a API Call how can i do it?

Comment: Where are the APIs being hosted? if you use api gateway then that service have cognito authorizer which is builtin. Otherwise you need your own code to decode and validate expire token.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cognito works with OAuth 2.0. You would need to understand how OAuth 2.0 works in order to set up your application. See a link below.

1 - You need to set up the Pool , then set up the  "callback url" and get the App Client Id and Secret Id.

2 - Once you login the "callback url" will return the 'Code'.

3 - With the Code , Client Id and Secret Id ; you will request the Access Token.

Understanding Amazon Cognito user pool OAuth 2.0 grants:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/

```js
class Cognito_auth{
  
  protected $appClientId;
  protected $appClientSecret;
  protected $userPoolId;
  protected $domain;
  protected $callbackUrl;
  protected $SignOutUrl;
  protected $Authorize;
  protected $Token;
  protected $UserInfo;
  
  public function __construct(){
  
       $this->appClientId = AWS_COGNITO_APP_ID;
       $this->appClientSecret = AWS_COGNITO_APP_SECRET;
       $this->userPoolId = AWS_COGNITO_POOL_ID;
       $this->domain = AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN;
       $this->callbackUrl = AWS_COGNITO_CALLBACK_URL;
       $this->SignOutUrl = AWS_COGNITO_SIGN_OUT_URL;
       $this->Authorize = $this->domain.'/oauth2/authorize';
       $this->Token = $this->domain.'/oauth2/token';
       $this->UserInfo = $this->domain.'/oauth2/userInfo';
  }

 
  /**
   * Get Login URL
   *
  */
  public function getLoginURL( $id = NULL )
  {
      $url = $this->Authorize."/?client_id=".$this->appClientId."&scope=openid&redirect_uri=".$this->callbackUrl."&response_type=code&state=".$id;
      return $url;
  }

  /**
   * Get Login URL
   *
  */
  public function getSignupURL()
  {
      $url = $this->domain."/signup?client_id=".$this->appClientId."&scope=openid&redirect_uri=".$this->callbackUrl."&response_type=code&state=".$id;
      return $url;
  }

  /**
   * Get Logout URL
   *
  */
  public function getLogoutURL()
  {
      $url = $this->domain."/logout?client_id=".$this->appClientId."&logout_uri=".$this->SignOutUrl;
      return $url;
  }

  /**
   * Get Token
   *
  */
  public function getToken( $code )
  {
      $data = array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => $this->appClientId,
        'code' => $code,
        'redirect_uri' => $this->callbackUrl,
      );
      $fields_string = http_build_query( $data );
      $authorization = $this->appClientId.':'.$this->appClientSecret;
      $headers = array(
       "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($authorization),
       "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      );
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->Token );
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      $err = curl_error($ch);
      if ($err) {
        //echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        return false;
      }
      curl_close($ch);
      $result = json_decode($result);
      return $result;
  }
 
 /**
   * Get User Info
   *
  */
  public function getUserInfo( $token )
  {
      $headers = array(
       "Authorization: Bearer ".$token,
       "cache-control: no-cache"
      );
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->UserInfo );
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      $err = curl_error($ch);
      if ($err) {
        //echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        return false;
      }
      curl_close($ch);
      $result = json_decode($result);
      return $result;
  }
}
```

Regards.
Ed.